# ActiveStorage issue to set record_type on active_storage_attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a problem for ActiveStorage

the case is I have a model named `Setting::Profile` and name of `Admin` table and attachment `:avatar`
for uploading process succeed, but when to get the picture can not be found because at table `active_storage_attachments` in attribute `record_type` stored with name `Setting::Profile`, supposed with name `Admin`

How to add a line to prepare for the `record_type` attribute?
Thanks

This my demo: https://github.com/SunDi3yansyah-forks/AppActiveStorage

[image: screenshot from 2018-07-11 01-24-48]

Comment: Can you post some code, the explanation is not clear enough to get the point. For example models and relations.

Comment: This my demo: https://github.com/SunDi3yansyah-forks/AppActiveStorage

Comment: Enough code! :) I will take a look.

Comment: I possibly found a solution. Check the last edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this problem (try in console).

If you set `profile = Account::Profile.last` then call `profile.avatar.attached?` it returns false. This is because the column `record_type` in `ActiveStorage::Attachment` is set to User.

So, you can not access the blob because `profile.avatar.blob` returns the following query:

```
SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 1], ["record_type", "Account::Profile"], ["name", "avatar"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

And the error: `Module::DelegationError: blob delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil`

**One possible workaround** that I found is to define Account::Profile as follows:

```
class Account::Profile < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "users"
    # has_one_attached :avatar # remove this

  def avatar
    ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(name: :avatar, record_type: 'User', record_id: self.id).last
  end

end
```

This works for showing the image but has the problem that `profile.avatar.class` is not [`ActiveStorage::Attached::One`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e8682c5bf051517b0b265e446aa1a7eccfd47bf7/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/one.rb) (like `User.last.avatar.class`) but `ActiveStorage::Attachment`.

So, you can not call for example `.attached?` method on it. You must use `profile.avatar.present?` to check if the avatar is present.

**A possible better solution** is to define the instance method avatar in this way:

```
def avatar
  ActiveStorage::Attached::One.new('avatar', User.find(id), dependent: :purge_later)
end
```

It is required to instantiate an object of `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` but the record must be `User` class (to match `record_type`), that's why `User.find(id)`.
Now all methods are available: `profile.avatar.methods`.

Comment: Thanks @iGian I've updated the code in the repository https://github.com/SunDi3yansyah-forks/AppActiveStorage/commit/963d1e83ebb9036b8d019d2ab53a3888fb3b4a93